# Mongoose/MongoDB - How to use promise with aggregate queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to perform 2 queries to 2 different collections in MongoDB via mongoose and then combine their results for a REST API response.

Example:

```
var result1 = Model1.aggregate([<operations here>]).exec()

var result2 = Model2.aggregate([<operations here>]).exec()

var allDone = Promise.all(result1,result2)

allDone.then(function(data1,data2){
//Do something with both data
})
```

I get this error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'readPreference' of undefined

Which used to happen when the function signature for the callback wasnt function(err,docs){...

If I use callbacks for Aggregators , it works but I didn't want to chain callbacks/the queries and thought this way would be more efficient.

I found this [Mongoose aggregate cursor promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37016641/mongoose-aggregate-cursor-promise)

But wanted to know if this is possible with native promises in a simpler way. 
I do not want to iterate through the cursor too as explained in the above SO answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
var allDone = Promise.all(result1,result2)
```

should have been

```
var allDone = Promise.all([result1,result2])
```